# store output in a variable to allow multiple greps

Tags: bash

I'm running a command inside of a bash script and grepping for a number that I'm logging.

```
RUN1=`node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor test.conf.js | grep milliseconds | egrep -o '[0-9]+'
```

I want to grep for other numbers stored within the terminal output so ideally I would like to do:

```
RUN1=`node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor test.conf.js`
GREP1= "$RUN1" | `grep milliseconds | egrep -o '[0-9]+`
GREP2= "$RUN1" | `grep seconds | egrep -o '[0-9]+`
```

But the GREP1 variable isn't being populated in the same way as RUN1 when it was all one line. I'm not a bash expert and I'm sure I'm missing something glaringly obvious.

Any ideas greatly appreciated
C

Comment: `GREP1=$(grep milliseconds <<<"$RUN1" | egrep -o '[0-9]+')` and the similar for `GREP2` (**note:** the *hearstring* is limited to bash, you can also `GREP1=$(echo "$RUN1" | ....)` if you need a more portable solution)

Comment: Thanks for this, if you'd like to add as an answer I'll mark it as the right one

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of what backquotes (or the preferred form, `$(...)`) do; they aren't just for running a command, but for capturing the output of a command to use where you would ordinarily have a literal string.